# I need to slow down about 4-5 times a low DC voltage motor

Tags: dc-motor

I have a 360 rotation stand for photography. It already has 2 speeds. What I need is an even lower speed. I need it to be around 4 -5 times slower. I saw a solution about putting some diodes in parallel. Will this work. The voltage is applied from only one 1.5V battery.

[image]
Attached is the board circuit.

Thank you all for the replies. I will try to take more photos tomorrow. Will also provide the specs of the motor.
About the gears I recently disassembled an old laser printer so I have a lot of spare gears.
Before I bought this rotating stand my intention was to use the motor of the printer to put it on a lazy Susan from Ikea but it had about 20 contact wires on it. Too complicated for me haha.

Thank you all but I did it in another way.
My main objective was to slow it down so I can take photos every second with my camera. It was a rotating display that I want to do photo-scanning with.  So I thought a better way. I just bought a time relay programmable switch kit to stop the table rotation every 0.2 seconds and wait as long as I want it to. This way it was much better because I have great control.

Comment: Please add some more details about the motor and your requirements, particularly around torque and how precise you need the adjustment to be. Consider as well using mechanical means such as adding/changing gears.

Comment: Details that may help would include the current speed and target speed of the rotation stand and what sort of gearing there is between the motor and the stand. It is difficult to imagine what kind of existing control would work with only 1.5V input. I wonder if the motor could be a stepper motor. What kind of sound does it make?

Comment: It looks like the board changes voltages with a switching regulator.  Need a block diagram with exact voltages running.

Comment: For that much change in the rotation rate, I suspect that it will be too feeble with the voltage reduced in an attempt to change the rotation rate. A physical change of the gearing (or the addition of gears) may provide superior performance.

Comment: try connecting the motor directly to the battery,  try different types of battery, eg: NiMH.

Answer (score 2):

Without a schematic It is impossible to tell. I believe you read diodes in series, not parallel. Your battery is 1.5V subtract 0.7 (voltage drop across one diode) from that you get 0.8V by using just one diode. I do not think the motor operate at that voltage. What happens as the battery voltage drops as it is being discharged. Switching to a NiCad battery may be your solution, it has a lower terminal voltage, 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Your device has a DC/DC converter in it which boosts the battery voltage to 5 V, then two silicon diodes in [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Series_circuits) to reduce motor voltage at the low speed setting. Each diode drops ~0.7 V, so the output voltage at the low speed setting should be ~5.0 - 1.4 = 3.6 V.

Motor speed is directly proportional to voltage. To get 4 times slower than the existing low speed setting you need ~3.6/4 = 0.9 V, which means you must drop an extra 2.7 V or so. This can be done with another 4 silicon diodes in series. Which diodes to use depends on how much current the motor draws. Based on the boost regulator IC [datasheet](http://file.yizimg.com/390228/2012041215332322.pdf) I am guessing it draws less than 50 mA, so popular [1N400x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N400x_general-purpose_diode) series or equivalent rectifier diodes should work. Alternatively you could try [1N4148](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4148_signal_diode) signal diodes which have higher voltage drop - or perhaps a mixture of both types - to get the voltage you want.

At lower voltage the motor draws less current and has lower torque, so it may run even slower due to friction. If this happens then you could try fewer diodes in series. You might also need to momentarily short out the extra diodes at startup so the motor has enough torque to overcome [stiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction) in the mechanism.

Comment: Thank you I think this would have worked if I tried to do it. But eventually, I did it in a completely different way. My objective was to slow it down so I can take photos every second with my camera. It was a rotating display that I want to do photo scanning with.  So I thought a better way. I just bought a time relay programmable switch kit to stop the table rotation every 0.2 seconds and wait as long as I want it to. This way it was much better because I have great control.